# Varias condiciones con IF

Tags: javascript

me gustaría saber como puedo realizar varias condiciones en una función dentro de un IF, de forma eficiente, ya que la que conozco me parece poco útil. Para ello pongo de ejemplo el típico ejercico de la caja registradora. Tenemos una caja registradora (en este caso el cambio solo puede ser con **monedas de 1,2 euros y billetes de 5,10 euros**, para simplificarlo), la función acepta 2 argumentos (pago y coste) y devuelve el cambio con las correspondientes monedas. El código que he implementado es este, pero me gustaría saber como mejorarlo para ejercicios más complejos:

```
function main (pago, coste){

    let cambio = pago - coste;
// Variable para el bucle que no se modifica, se me ocurrio hacerlo así
    const cambio2 = cambio;

//Variables para calcular las monedas correspondientes
    let monedas1euro = 0;
    let monedas2euros = 0;
    let billetes5euros = 0;
    let billetes10euros = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < cambio2; i++){
    if(cambio >= 10){
        billetes10euros ++;
        cambio -= 10;
    }else if(cambio >=5) {
        billetes5euros ++;
        cambio -= 5;
    }else if(cambio >= 2){
        monedas2euros ++;
        cambio -= 2;
    }else if(cambio >=1){
        monedas1euro ++;
        cambio -= 1;
    }
}
    console.log("el cambio es " + cambio2 + " corresponde a " + billetes10euros + " billete de 10 euros", billetes5euros + " billete de 5 euros", monedas2euros + " monedas de 2 euros", monedas1euro + " monedas de 1 euro",);
}

main(20, 5); //devuelve el cambio es 15 corresponde a 1 billete de 10 euros 1 billete de 5 euros 0 monedas de 2 euros 0 monedas de 1 euro
```

EDIT:
Con ejercicios más complejos me refiero a este en concreto, ya que pensando como abordarlo no lo tengo muy claro, porque hacerlo como en este me parece bastante poco útil, y ya he pasado por este caso otras veces. Pongo el ejercicio en cuestión de [freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/):

[image: Ejercicio parte 1]
[image: Ejercicio parte 2]

Comment: Saludos. Creo es necesario pongas esos "ejercicios más complejos" ya que dependiendo todos los escenarios que quieras abarcar, será el código; desde luego no olvides poner lo que tienes ya realizado y en que falla o devuelve resultado equivocado; así llegará la lluvia de ideas respecto a lo que planteas.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, ahi pongo el ejercicio complejo en cuestión, estoy aprendiendo javascript desde cero e intento mejorar mi código a la par que mejoro mis conocimientos

Comment: Lo que pasa aca es que cada uno puede tomar una estrategia diferente dependiendo el ejercicio... En este caso, no esta mal hacer lo que haces... el que sigue no es mas complejo, es un poco mas largo... pero no siempre vas a tener estrategias que simplifiquen.. a veces vas a tener que escribir mucho codigo. Podrias ir iterando sobre el monto y llamar a una funcion que haga los calculos por ejemplo.. pero son solo estrategias.. y estan basados en opiniones....

Comment: Entiendo, me gusta ver posibles soluciones de otros programadores para coger ideas y mejorar mi código, y viendo algunos códigos me da la sensación de que el mio es muy simple, pero al final lo que leo es que al principio lo importante es asimilar conceptos y con el tiempo mejoraré como escribo el código.

Comment: La clave es crear el arreglo con las denominaciones e iterar sobre él.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la estructura switch case y adaptarla a tu ejemplo, es mucho más elegante y el código se vuelve más legible con ella:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Esta puede ser una solución al primer ejemplo:

```
function main(pago, coste){

  let cambio = pago -coste,
  cambio2 = cambio;
  
  let monedas1euro = 0,
  monedas2euros = 0,
  billetes5euros = 0,
  billetes10euros = 0;

  for(let i=0; i<cambio2; i++){

    switch(cambio){

      case cambio >= 10:
        billetes10euros ++;
        cambio -= 10;
        break;

      case cambio >=5:
        billetes5euros ++;
        cambio -= 5;
        break;

      case cambio >= 2:
        monedas2euros ++;
        cambio -= 2;
        break;

      case cambio >= 1:
        monedas1euro ++;
        cambio -= 1;
        break;
    }
  }

  console.log("el cambio es " + cambio2 + " corresponde a " + billetes10euros + " billete de 10 euros", billetes5euros + " billete de 5 euros", monedas2euros + " monedas de 2 euros", monedas1euro + " monedas de 1 euro",);
}

main(20, 5)
```

Comment: ¿Cómo lo implementarias?

A mi se me ocurre hacer una función que los casos sean con las monedas (case "PENNY: , case "NICKEL" ... y que devuelva el valor de esa moneda)

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta principal, revísala y avísame si te funciona

Comment: Faltaría un break en el ultimo caso "case cambio >= 1:" verdad?

Comment: Sí, mil disculpas por ello. Acabo de corregirlo.

Comment: Tranquilo, me sirve la solución gracias. ¿Podrias aplicarlo al ejercicio más complejo que pase?

Comment: Sip, estoy en ello. Está un poco enredado, pero ahí voy. Bien lo tenga listo y funcionando, lo pongo en el comentario principal.

Comment: @pablusprogramador ¿tienes Discord?, si es así, pásamelo, para poder hablar contigo de este ejercicio mientras lo resuelvo.

Comment: Si, agregame y hablamos por alli Pech00✈#1284 ¡gracias!

Comment: @bkf1 perdón, lograste solucionarlo con el ejemplo de freecodecamp?